# LINQ search / match

Tags: c#, linq

let assume we have an array like this:

```
 var caps = new[] { "1512x", "001xx", "27058", "201xx", "4756x" };
```

(original array is huge and come from another linq query)

What I need is to create a LINQ statement accepting a value and tries to match with one of the values on the foreseen array.

For example if I use "15121" I need to match the "1512x" value on the array and return it.
Obviously, if I use "27058" it finds the exact match and simply return it.

Is it possible in LINQ?
The "wildcard" char on the array is "x", but I can change it.

Thanks in advance!
Valerio

Comment: Do you have the code of the matcing predicate? Does it have a name somewhere in your code?

Comment: I used "cap" as you request

Comment: Sounds like a 'Contains' as you already have the value as parameter.

Comment: is it really 'x' or just a random character?

Comment: He already said `x` is the `wildcard` character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
var value = "15121";
var caps = new[] { "1512x", "001xx", "27058", "201xx", "4756x" };
var match = caps
  .FirstOrDefault(c => new Regex("^" + c.Replace("x", "[0-9]") + "$").IsMatch(value));
if (match != null)
  Console.WriteLine("{0} matches {1}", value, match);
```

The "pattern" `001xx` is converted into the regular expression `^001[0-9][0-9]$` and so on. Then the first matching regular expressions is found.

But if the `caps` is huge it might not perform so well because each regular expression has to be compiled and converted into a state machine until a match is found.

Comment: thank you for this answer. It works like a charm.
I'll make it the answer.
Is it possible to make it LINQ to Entities safe? (for another idea I have).

Comment: @Valerio: EF cannot translate the regex stuff into SQL so you will have to append a `ToEnumerable()` to your EF LINQ query before appending `FirstOrDefault`. Thus the at least the last part of the query will be executed client side.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have a predicate method, something like this (or something equivalent using Regex, as described in another answer):

```
static bool Match(string pattern, string exact)
{
    if(pattern.Length != exact.Length) return false;
    for(var i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++)
        if(pattern[i] != exact[i] && pattern[i] != 'x') 
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Then the LINQ query can look like this:

```
var found = caps.Single(x => Match(x, yourSearch));
```